# creating a multidimensional array from queries

Tags: php

I'm having difficulty constructing a multidimensional array based on queries fetched from a mysql database.  The purpose is to prepare the result for json encoding.  Having problems here.

Structure I’m aiming for:

```
Array ( 
    [68] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 64 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [id] => 65 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada...) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [id] => 66 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) ) 
    [69] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 64 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [id] => 65 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada...) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [id] => 66 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) ) 
...etc
)
```

From:

```
//this is a list of unknown length
$array_ids = (68, 69, 70, etc... );   // or:

Array ( 
    [0] => 68 
    [1] => 69
    [2] => 70 
    [3] => 71 
    etc..  
)


//this is a known length 
$array_contents = ( array ( array ( [id], [description]) );  // or:

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 64 
        [description] =>yada, yada, yada... ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 65 
        [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 66 
        [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) )
```

My attempt:

```
foreach($array_ids as $row){
    $result = array($row=>array());
    foreach($array_contents as $key => $value){
        $result [$row][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
    [68] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 64 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [id] => 65 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada...) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [id] => 66 
            [description] => yada, yada, yada... ) )
```

)

...and that’s where it stops.  It doesn’t go on to the next row id of 69, 70, etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
$result = array($row=>array());
```

Every pass through `$array_ids` it's completely wiping out `$result` and repopulating it with one single item from `$array_contents`, rather than appending it to the end.

Replacing it with this should work:

```
$result[$row] = array();
```

**Here's a full working version:**

```
$array_ids = array(68,69,70);

$array_contents = array(
    array( 
        'id' => 64, 
        'description' => 'yada, yada, yada...'
    ),
  array( 
        'id' => 65,
        'description' => 'yada, yada, yada2...'
    ),
    array( 
    'id' => 66,
    'description' => 'yada, yada, yada3...'
    ),
);

foreach($array_ids as $row){
    $result[$row] = array();
    foreach($array_contents as $key => $value){
        $result [$row][$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

**Here's the output:**

```
array(3) {
  [68]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(64)
      ["description"]=>
      string(19) "yada, yada, yada..."
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(65)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada2..."
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(66)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada3..."
    }
  }
  [69]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(64)
      ["description"]=>
      string(19) "yada, yada, yada..."
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(65)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada2..."
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(66)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada3..."
    }
  }
  [70]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(64)
      ["description"]=>
      string(19) "yada, yada, yada..."
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(65)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada2..."
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(66)
      ["description"]=>
      string(20) "yada, yada, yada3..."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ...thank you for actually explaining the error in my logic.  That is EXTREMELY helpful.  Too bad I already accepted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following array structure and logic its working , My logic is bit different

```
$array = array(68,69,70);
$nextArray = array(
    array(
        'id'=>64,
        'desc'=>'test'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>65,
        'desc'=>'test'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>66,
        'desc'=>'test'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>67,
        'desc'=>'test'
    ),
);
$tempArray = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($nextArray as $key => $value1){
        $tempArray[$value][$key] = $value1;
    }
}
var_dump($tempArray);
```

output :

```
array
  68 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => int 64
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => int 65
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => int 66
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      3 => 
        array
          'id' => int 67
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
  69 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => int 64
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => int 65
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => int 66
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      3 => 
        array
          'id' => int 67
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
  70 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => int 64
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => int 65
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      2 => 
        array
          'id' => int 66
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
      3 => 
        array
          'id' => int 67
          'desc' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: ...spot on.  ...I don't know why I suck at arrays so bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, having re-read the question, try the following:

```
$outputArray = array();

foreach( $array_ids as $id ){
  $outputArray[$id] = $array_contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code following way & shorter

```
$result = array();
foreach($array_ids as $row){
    foreach($array_contents as $key => $value){
        $result [$row][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```